# How could i manage to read/write german "Umlaute" and special chars like é via java.net.Socket.Socket?

Tags: java, sockets, server, character-encoding

i am struggling with the charset-problem. I run a Java Server with a java.net.Socket.Socket connection and a JavaFX client. I (currently) use PrintWriter and BufferedReader on both sides to communicate. But when i send sth like "ÄÄÄ" and put it out to the console on the server i get "Ã?Ã?Ã?". My code is like this:

```
//on both sides ... also tried with UTF_8 - result was also like this
writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_16));
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_16));

//client writes
writer.write("ÄÄÄ");
writer.flush();
//... and reads
line = reader.readLine()
//server the same
```

What should i change to properly send german umlaute or letters with accents ect.?

Comment: The *console* can't print the characters, but you're transmitting them correctly, apart from using `readLine()` but not sending a line terminator.

Comment: i checked it ... i can print umlaute.